# Copy a file using .bat to another location

Tags: batch-file, file-copying

Is it possible to use a wildcard (instead of hard-coding entire file name) to copy files from one location to another?  Also, I'd like to attach HHSS (hours and seconds) to the file name.

Example:  Everyday, our system generates a few files with following name format:

```
GL_YYYYMMDD.txt
AP_YYYYMMDD.txt
```

I want to copy/move these files to another folder called "Backups" and attach HHSS (hours and seconds) so file name would look something like:

```
GL_YYYYMMDDHHSS
AP_YYYYMMDDHHSS
```

What I have so far:

```
Rem Determine date
Set mm1=%date:~4,2%
Set dd1=%date:~7,2%
Set yyyy1=%date:~10,4%

REM Determine Time
Set HH=%time:~0,2%
IF "%HH:~0,1%" == " " SET HH=0%HH:~1,1%
Set MM=%time:~3,2%
Set SEC=%time:~6,2%
Set runtime=%HH%%MM%%SEC%

rem Seconday date backup
cd E:\Blackline\DailyFiles

copy GL* E:\Blackline\Backups\"GL*%runtime%"

pause
```

Comment: Use the `FOR` command to list the files you want to process.  Then you can get the exact output file name you want copied to your output.

Comment: The issue is, the file name changes everyday.  File name today is GL_20170828 and tomorrow will be GL_20170829 so I am not sure how to copy this file to a backup folder and add HHSS to its name (GL_201708280547).  Also, I am very very new to batch scripting.

Comment: I can only assume that `yyyyMMdd` is relevant to the specific file. It makes no sense whatsoever to append the current time to that name, as that time is relevant only to the batch naming process not the file itself. Would using the file creation time not be a better, more relevant, thing to append?

Comment: The YYYYMMDD would be the date a file gets created from our system.  Also, that is the naming format required by our third party.  This is the reason why I was thinking about adding HHMM to this name so in case we have to create two files in one day for unknown reason it can be handled and saved.

Comment: Granularity is a consideration in such cases.  Is it possible two files could be generated in the same minute?  (In this case, probably not; but it is a question worth asking.)  Same second?  Same centisecond?  Just a thought for future use; the scenario you describe suggests this really isn't likely to be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  If you remove the .txt extensions, copy the files, then add the extension back you end up with your copied files retaining their original names with the added timestamp.

```
Rem Determine date
Set mm1=%date:~4,2%
Set dd1=%date:~7,2%
Set yyyy1=%date:~10,4%

REM Determine Time
Set HH=%time:~0,2%
IF "%HH:~0,1%" == " " SET HH=0%HH:~1,1%
Set MM=%time:~3,2%
Set SEC=%time:~6,2%
Set runtime=%HH%%MM%%SEC%

rem Seconday date backup
cd E:\Blackline\DailyFiles

rename *.txt *.

copy GL* E:\Blackline\Backups\GL*%runtime%.txt

rename *. *.txt


pause
```

Comment: Note that this is locale independent - I get `/0` for `mm1`, `/3` for `dd1`, and I got the weekday for `yyyy1`, although this works in OP's machine.

Answer (score 2):

Star wildcards ( `*` ) in the destination filespec only work with an exact replication of the same columns of the filename from source to destination, terminated and restarted by the last dot ( `.` ) as that tradtionally represents the file type or "extension":

```
M:\t\a>dir
 Volume in drive M is MyDrive
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-EF01

 Directory of M:\t\a

08/28/2017  05:42 PM    <DIR>          .
08/28/2017  05:42 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test1.dat
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test2.dat
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test3.dat
               3 File(s)             51 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,050,894,336 bytes free

M:\t\a>copy test*.dat ..\b\test*.abc
test1.dat
test2.dat
test3.dat
        3 file(s) copied.

M:\t\a>dir ..\b
 Volume in drive M is MyDrive
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-EF01

 Directory of M:\t\b

08/28/2017  05:44 PM    <DIR>          .
08/28/2017  05:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test1.abc
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test2.abc
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test3.abc
               3 File(s)             51 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,050,894,336 bytes free

M:\t\a>
```

To insert additional components in the filename, you're going to need to get them one at a time.  I recommend a `FOR` loop.

Side note:  be cautious with possible spaces in your date and time extractions.  For example, check that 9am is represented as `"09:00"` instead of `" 9:00"`.

Here's a quick example of the `FOR` loop using your proposed mechanism for grabbing the time (which I did *not* confirm works in the morning):

```
@echo off
REM Determine Time
Set HH=%time:~0,2%
IF "%HH:~0,1%" == " " SET HH=0%HH:~1,1%
Set MM=%time:~3,2%
Set SEC=%time:~6,2%
Set runtime=%HH%%MM%%SEC%

for %%F in (test*.dat) do copy "%%F" "..\b\%%~nF%runtime%%%~xF"
```

Which yields the following results, appending time to the end of the `test1`/`test2`/`test3` part of the filename:

```
M:\t\a>dir
 Volume in drive M is MyDrive
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-EF01

 Directory of M:\t\a

08/28/2017  05:42 PM    <DIR>          .
08/28/2017  05:42 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/28/2017  05:51 PM               227 copywithtime.bat
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test1.dat
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test2.dat
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test3.dat
               3 File(s)             51 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,050,894,336 bytes free

M:\t\a>copywithtime
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.

M:\t\a>dir ..\b
 Volume in drive M is MyDrive
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-EF01

 Directory of M:\t\b

08/28/2017  05:44 PM    <DIR>          .
08/28/2017  05:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test1175134.dat
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test2175134.dat
08/28/2017  05:42 PM                17 test3175134.dat
               3 File(s)             51 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,050,894,336 bytes free

M:\t\a>
```

Comment: Hmm.. Would it be better if you refer `*` to it's actual name - asterisk?

Comment: Also note the time is local dependent, I don't get correct results on my zh-TW machine, although this work in OP's machine

Comment: @SteveFest I do not understand the question about the wildcard.  Can you expand on the question a bit?

Comment: `*` <-- This thing is called `asterisk`, so I think it will be better if your answer call it `asterisk` instead of `star`.

Comment: @SteveFest Oh, LOL, got it.  Actually, while it is called an asterisk in English, in DOS (whence came its use as a wildcard) it was always called "star".  Just like "period" became known as "dot".  Just one of those legacy/jargon things.  :-)

Comment: Oh well. I didn't know that.